# Intercepting __getattr__ in a Python 2.3 old-style mixin class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a large Python 2.3 based installation with 200k LOC. As part of a migration project I need to intercept all attribute lookups of all old-style class.

Old legacy code:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    ...
```

My idea is to inject a common mixin class like

```
class Foo(Bar, Mixin):
    ...

class Mixin:

    def __getattr__(self, k)
        print repr(self), k
        return Foo.__getattr__(self, k)
```

However I am running always into a recursion because `Foo.__getattr__` resolves
to `Mixin.__getattr__`.

Is there any way to fix the code for Python 2.3 old-style classes?

Comment: Do any of the old style classes already implement `__getattr__` ?

Comment: of course, __getattribute__() was introduced with  new-style classes

Comment: I mean do any of the old style classes **in your code base**, before you add your mixin, implement `__getattr__`

Comment: Please do say that you're migrating this code to **Python 3**...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this is irrelevant. I asked a very clear question and I don't need a discussion about Python 3 here.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Just because Python 3 is not an option here?

Comment: I downvoted this question until it is given more detail ... as it currently stands it is too broad, eg you require solutions that do not involve transitioning to new style classes, or that work with ZODB but have specified neither constraint in the question.  Once its improved I'll bump it!

Comment: I have clearly asked that this is about Python 2.3 only. I neither mentioned new-style classes, nor Python 3...please read carefully instead of interpreting unwritten assumptions.

Comment: @user4857 In your comments on answers you have clearly indicated that solutions involving new style classes or that use `__setattr__` are "not suitable" ... these are not "unwritten assumptions" ... **you** wrote them.  If these constraints form part of your question, add them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already injecting mixins, why not add `object` as parent, to make them new style

```
class Foo(Mixin, Bar, object):
    ...
```

And then use `super`

```
class Mixin(object):

    def __getattr__(self, k)
        print repr(self), k
        return super(Mixin, self).__getattr__(k)
```

Comment: Not suitable. I can not turn several hundred classes into new-style classes without breaking all and everything (different inheritance etc).

Comment: The thing is that Mixins is not suitable for old-style classes. Because there wasn't any "call-parent" functionality. You still can call `return Bar.__getattr__(self, k)` manually, but this will fix only your `Foo` class problem.

Comment: This is not true. The Zope 2 code-base uses mixins extensively since 1999

Comment: Problem in your code that Mixin calls `Foo.__getattr__`, but should call `Bar.__getattr__`. If there is already project that uses mixins in python just look examples in it

Comment: This is also wrong. Bar.__getattr__ will delegate back to A.__getattr__  -> welcome to the recursion hell

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the classes in your code base implement `__setattr__` or `__getattr__` then one approach is to intercept `__setattr__` in your Mixin, writing the value to another reserved attribute, then read it back in `__getattr__`

```
class Mixin:
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        # write the value into some special reserved space
        namespace = self.__dict__.setdefault("_namespace", {})
        namespace[attr] = value

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # reject special methods so e.g. __repr__ can't recurse
        if attr.startswith("__") and attr.endswith("__"):
            raise AttributeError

        # do whatever you wish to do here ...
        print repr(self), attr

        # read the value from the reserved space
        namespace = self.__dict__.get("_namespace", {})
        return namespace[attr]
```

Example:

```
class Foo(Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
```

Then

```
>>> Foo().x
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x10c4dad88> x
```

Clearly this won't work if any of your `Foo` classes implement `__setattr__` or `__getattr__` themselves.

Comment: Nice idea but also not going to work since since object instances exist in terms of persisted object(ZODB). So there is no chance because  your __setattr__() was not involved

Comment: I think you should give some details on the types of classes involved in your question ... if they are zope persisted then that will be relevant for any potential solution.

Comment: e.g if all of these classes are ZODB persisted, then a potential solution may be to monkey patch the ZODB bases classes themselves, so that objects loaded from the database are using a patched zope base class